# How do i get my SVG Shape to move around a div using my arrow keys? I

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i am building a basic video game very similar too those shooting craft games where the ammo increases to triple shots. I'm currently working with a div element in html. I designed the background to be handled in css which is why the html is pretty empty and you dont see an image tag. I want to work with designing shapes in html using svg and javascript. While i created the shape i wanted to, when i went into js to try and run some code, mainly document.addEventListener("keypress", function(e)) i was not getting any response from the event what so ever when i console.log it and i was also getting no hello world console.log to test to make sure that my function was written properly. Im a bit stuck on this. I have tried to use the same approach using code similar to the pong paddle but in js and still nothing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    #img-container {
      background: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/RY4uivIh-ik/maxresdefault.jpg");
      background-size: 100% 100%;
      border: 1px solid red;
      height: 400px;
      position: relative;
      top: 10px;
      left: 10px;
      width: 600px;
    }
    
    #triangle {
      fill: red;
      margin-left: 50px;
    }
    
    svg {
      position: absolute;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="img-container">
    <svg id="svg">
              <polygon points="250,60 100,400 400,400" id="triangle"/>
            </svg>
  </div>
  <script>
    var shapeOne = document.getElementById("triangle");

    shapeOne.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      var keycode = e.which || e.code;
      if (keycode === 38) {
        console.log("up");
      }
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I changed `shapeOne.addEventListener` to `document.addEventListener` and the message `"up"` was logged to the console every time I hit the up arrow.

Comment: Awesome stuff #Ray Toal. That worked great. Why wasn't shapeOne working if i had declared it as a variable with the dom as the value? This method worked fine with my pong game i created using divs.

Comment: It's because there is no reason that the SVG shape would receive a key event. :) Not sure how you got it to work before. Did you programmatically set the focus to a shape?

Comment: No! In a pong game project i built a few days ago. I got the paddles to work using the the dom, but storing the dom int variables. I had no problem access the data i wanted. Everything console logged like i wanted and when hit the up arrow key the div move up whatever pixel i wanted it to.  but again I was also just using div's not SVG. This is my first time playing around heavily with SVG. Which is why i asked for help to begin with. I can show you my code on gitHub if you like. https://github.com/Urihel/Pong-the-Div-version

Comment: I think im just gonna see if SetInterval in js works better with getting the shape to move around with the arrow Keys.

Comment: Hopefully you can move the div just fine. It shouldn't matter what the div contains; it can be positioned with JavaScript as long as it has the right position attributes, etc. Best.